# Please, explain the joke about a walkie talkie

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, jokes

> Q. What do you get when you cross a parrot and a caterpillar?
>   A. A walkie talkie.

What feature of caterpillars was chosen to create this joke?

As far as I know a *walkie talkie* is a device with headphones for listening to music. And a *caterpillar* is a stage of a butterfly development.
I agree, a parrot talks, but does a caterpillar walk?

---

@oerkelens corrected me, *a walkie-talkie* is some kind of radio, but what does it have similar to caterpillars?

Comment: I don't know about the caterpillar, but isn't a walkie talkie a device to talk to someone else (like a telephone), rather than what you describe? That sounds more like a walkman.

Comment: @oerkelens may be, I'm not a native speakes, perhaps I mixed those together. but the meaning of 'some kind of radio" makes the joke more strange for me.

Comment: I guess caterpillars walk (they're walkies), and parrots talk (they're talkies), so combined you get a walkie talkie. If that's all there is to it, I don't think it's an extremely funny joke.

Comment: A walkie-talkie is a hand-held radio, the sort of things police officers use or you'd perhaps take skiing. Partly superseded by mobile 'phones. I think the joke then hinges on parrots == talk, caterpillar == walk (except caterpillars crawl through a series of compressions and rarefactions {if that's applicable to a biological system!}, as they don't actually have legs...)

Comment: I thought now, if it is a radio, maybe it reffers to its antennae?

Comment: Yeah, it's a pretty lame joke, but it's simply that parrots talk and caterpillars walk.

Comment: Caterpillars have antennae.

Comment: Yes, it's a lame joke, I suspect it's for children.

Comment: @Prof Yaffle: I don't know if you've ever looked closely at a caterpillar, but if you had you would have seen lots and lots of legs. (Okay, I just checked, and etymologists actually call them *prolegs* because they're not evolutionarily related to the legs of other insects, but they're definitely used for locomotion.)

Comment: @PeterShor Well, you learn something new every day - thanks - they apparently have six "legs", just like other insects: http://bugs.bio.usyd.edu.au/learning/resources/Entomology/internalAnatomy/imagePages/caterpillar_prolegs.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just by way of confirming the consensus among commenters above that the "walkie" refers to the many legs a caterpillar is supposed to have, I note that a common version of this joke involves crossing a parrot with a centipede (for example, [here](https://www.jokelabs.com/2007/04/492-what-do-you-get-when-you-cross-a-parrot-with-a-centipede.html), [here](http://www.funnydot.com/jokes/What-Do-You-Get-When-You-Cross-A-Parrot-And-A-Centipede.html), and [here](http://www.kidsjokesoftheday.com/htmls/kids-jokes/Animal-Jokes-for-Kids/20150601185948_100.html)). Since the name *centipede* derives from the equivalent of "hundred foot," it probably makes a better animal choice than *caterpillar*. [One online source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Jokes/comments/346zqr/what_do_you_get_when_you_cross_a_millipede_with_a/) ups the foot quotient by using a *millipede* instead of a *centipede*.

But [a](https://boldomatic.com/view/post/fqTTLQ) [lot](http://www.kidsjokesoftheday.com/htmls/kids-jokes/Animal-Jokes-for-Kids/20150415181111_322.html) [of](http://www.funology.com/mix-match-jokes/) [sites](http://boyslife.org/jokes/4768/a-caterpillar-and-a-parrot/) [go](http://www.kappit.com/img/8546/what-do-you-get-when-you-cross-a-caterpillar-and-a-parrot-a-walkie-talkie/) [with](https://books.google.com/books?id=xNl8DZ540XcC&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=cross+a+caterpillar+and+a+parrot&source=bl&ots=sJYJrkG1M_&sig=6e0lMoLugM0uuVQFB1j8kqYh0Oc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiG0abG-uzMAhVQ82MKHQ4aBCIQ6AEIUjAM#v=onepage&q=cross%20a%20caterpillar%20and%20a%20parrot&f=false) [*caterpillar*](http://jokesareawesome.com/tag/parrot), maybe because more people know what a caterpillar is than know what a centipede or millipede is. Other parrot jokes on sites that tell this joke include "What's orange and rhymes with parrot?" and "What do you call a parrot that flew away?" and "What do you get if you cross a parrot with a shark?"—so the level of wit here isn't exactly Shakespearean.